Nissan Xterra 2006 ECM Replaced with used one and needs some kind of programming? Not the keys because I tried that. Engine light is on and key Light
Hello and thanks for reading my post. I bought a ECM from Ebay, the numbers matched the ECM 5E MEC-451 I installed it, the fans turned off instantly thankfully because the old one had the fans running constantly and by the way the dealership determined the original ECM was bad. The key light on dash is on and so is the check engine light. I have tried to program the keys but my programmers will  only go so far and say system failed to connect. I also have a J2534 box and a PCM tool super 67 in 1  J2534 box I bought from Ebay I have not known how to use yet? Does anyone know what I need to do next? I believe I have all the tools but just do not know much in running them, just need some guidance. Thanks in advance. Robb 2006 Nissan Xterra 4x4 with chipped key.

Perhaps searching for Nissan Xterra forums may help. In addition, alldata.diy or Mitchell Data provide second to none service manuals.
